# How to test/run last iteration of loop using enumerate on a list of strings

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I have program in which I loop over a list of subfolders (dir_list) which is obtained using os.walk. Now, I loop over the full list using enumerate, as follows:

```
for day_index, day_folder in enumerate(dir_list[:]):
```

Now, I'd like to test the code within this loop on the last element (without running the whole loop, because the program is quite large). So I do the following:

```
for day_index, day_folder in enumerate(dir_list[-1]):
```

However, now that dir_list is a single element enumerate behaves differently and starts to iterate through the single element, which happens to be a string, resulting in day_folder becoming the first element of the string. This is of course not what I want to happen. But I understand why it is happening.

How can I run this loop - for testing purposes - just on the last element of the list (my last subfolder). I don't want to change my code by removing the for loop, and I need to retain the counter (day_index).

Comment: If I understand  correctly, do you want `enumerate(list(dir_list[-1]))` ?

Comment: Any reason to create a copy of `dir_list` on the first line ? (done by `dir_list[:]`)

Comment: @FlorianGD no, this returns the same result. What I needed was enumerate(dir_list[-1:]) i.e to force a list slice with the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

```
for day_index, day_folder in enumerate(dir_list[-1:]):
```

This is simple [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).

Comment: You see, I knew it would be that simple! I could have sworn I tried this.... But anyway, it works. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! :) Please accept my post as an answer.

Comment: Done. Was waiting for the 10 minute window to pass.